# jQuery that search children if they have a specific class, if they dont , it will take a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I need to write a jQuery that loop a ul childrens li in all sub levels , and find if any of those childrens has a class test  do nothing but if none of them have that class , i want to give the main parent ul a  certain class, 
this is a sample of the code,

```
<ul class="level1" id="navigation">
    <li class="hasChildNodes"><a href="#"><span>Community</span></a>
        <ul class="menuLevelContainer level2 hasChildNodes">
            <li class=""><a href="#"><span>Blogs</span></a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><span>Discussions</span></a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><span>Photos</span></a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><span>Polls & Surveys</span></a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#><span>Suggestions</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=""><a href="/Events/Pages/default.aspx"><span>Events</span></a></li>
    <li class="hasChildNodes"><a href="/News/Pages/default.aspx"><span>News</span></a>
        <ul class="menuLevelContainer level2 hasChildNodes">
            <li class=""><a href="#"><span>Annoucements</span></a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><span>Good Morning
                Done</span></a></li></ul>
    </li>
```

and i want to search all the childrens of the ul to see if it has a child witha that named class, and if not i want to give the ul the class test for example, but i want to give the specific ul the class , so shouldn;t i catch it first, this or something ??

Comment: is test the name of the class you are looking for? Are you only concerned with li elements possessing that class?

Answer (score 3):

```
 if($('ul li.test').length == 0){
   $('ul').addClass('classToAdd');
 }
```

You can make this more specific if required by giving the ul element an Id and changing ul to #someId in the code above:

```
 if($('#someId li.test').length == 0){
   $('#someId').addClass('classToAdd');
 }
```

Comment: 1) You're assuming there's only one `<ul>` that the OP wants to target 2) You want `==` (equality operator), not `=` (assignment).

Comment: oops - you are correct JP - thanks for spotting that rogue "="!

Answer (score 0):

```
var ul = $('ul#some-id');

if (!ul.find('li.test')[0]) {
    ul.addClass('some-class');
}
```

The code within the `if` block will only execute if `ul.find('li.test')` returns a non-empty collection. Please change the class "test" to whatever you want to test the `<li/>` children for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0 ;

$('ul')find('li').each(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass('test')) {

      $i++;
    }

});

if($i == 0 ) {

   $('ul').addClass('main');

}
```